# Basic concepts about matrices and their decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am studying the basics of linear algebra and I have some questions that I can not conclude them by my own.

Let $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n} $

- $A$ can always be expressed as a LU decomposition?
- $A$ can always be expressed in the reduced echelon form?
- $A$ can be expressed as a QR decomposition?

Comment: You're definitely not supposed to be able to answer to the third question by your own. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First one: by definition a triangular matrix is square (wait, that sounds funny)...so the first one is not really applicable in general to $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ - it is also not true that all square matrices have a LU decomposition. For necessary and sufficient conditions see this article: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506382v1.pdf
- Yes, row equivalence is an equivalence relation, and every equivalence class contains one matrix in reduced echelon form. You can prove it by induction on $m$. As a reference you can refer to Matrices and linear transformations, theorem 1.18 [Cullen].
- Yes, ref: Proposition 16.11 in The linear algebra a beginning graduate student ought to know [Golan]